# How to run a Cobol application on Hercules mainframe emulator (Terminal 3270)

Tags: cobol, mainframe, terminal-emulator, vsam, legacy-app

I am beginner to mainframe applications and want to perform a simple POC for understanding where I want to run a sample Cobol application on Hercules mainframe emulator with terminal 3270, application also consist of JCL, BMS, VSAM files so, also want to know how can I connect the emulator to database and store VSAM files.
Please share information on this.

I have installed Hercules emulator, Crypto term terminal and setup the emulator and reached to TSO main menu. I have application folder and want to run this folder on emulator. Please help me out.

Comment: Here's the documentation for Hercules: [The Hercules System/370, ESA/390, and z/Architecture Emulator](http://www.hercules-390.org/).  Hercules by itself doesn't do anything.  You also have to load an operating system.  I'm most familiar with MVS 3.8, but there are others.  Once you pick and install an operating system, you can find manuals for that operating system online.  Unless you are a systems programmer expert in your particular operating system, you will need to hire a tutor to guide you step by painful step in setting up your operating system.

Comment: My mistake.  Here's a more recent version.  [The Hercules System/370, ESA/390, and z/Architecture Emulator](https://hercules-390.github.io/html/).  Again, I'm most familiar with MVS 3.8.